# Exception when trying to create an AWT window in java

Tags: java, bash

So recently I want to learn AWT and borrowed a book that showes following code:

```
/*Listing2301.java*/

import java.awt.*;

class Listing2301{
        public static void main(String[] args){
                Frame wnd = new Frame("Einfaches Fenster");

                wnd.setSize(400,300);
                wnd.setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

This code does compile. According to the book this code should generate an empty window with no function whatsoever, but when I try to execute it it throws an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.awt.HeadlessException: No X11 DISPLAY
>   variable was set, but this program performed an operation which
>   requires it.
>           at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:207)
>           at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:535)
>           at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:420)
>           at Listing2301.main(Listing2301.java:7)

I am working with the vi editor from the ubuntu bash, that I have installed on my Windows 10 PC.

My programming professor suggested typing `export DISPLAY=:0.0` into the bash.
After compiling the code and executing it once again, the error message changed to:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to
>   X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
>           at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
>           at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
>           at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:110)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195)
>           at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:102)
>           at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:81)
>           at java.awt.Window.initGC(Window.java:467)
>           at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:487)
>           at java.awt.Window.(Window.java:536)
>           at java.awt.Frame.(Frame.java:420)
>           at Listing2301.main(Listing2301.java:7)

How do I get that empty AWT window? Is the code wrong? Or do I need to configure the bash differently?

Comment: Seriously, why do you want to study AWT? It has been considered obsolete for something 20 years now.

Comment: I heard that it makes the introduction into swing easier. And all the books I've found about swing build upon AWT knowledge, that I don't have.

Comment: Should I ignore AWT and straight up jump into swing?

Comment: You should probably be studying JavaFX with Java 8 anyway, not Swing. But if you want to study Swing, it really doesn't require AWT knowledge. Try the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu subsystem of Windows 10 is basically a separate operating system within the same computer. Very much like a virtual machine - it can access your disk, but it can't run any Windows EXE files.

The Java that it runs is the *Linux* Java. Not the Windows Java, which is an EXE file. As such, it cannot access the Windows GUI. It looks for an X server running on the machine as it usually does on Linux machine. But such a server usually doesn't run on a Windows machine.

You should be running your graphical program under Windows, not in the Ubuntu subsystem. Non-graphical Java programs, however, should have no problem.

Comment: I use **javac <filename>** to compile and **java <classname>** to compile and run my code. So you are saying that this isn't supposed to work?

Comment: @Rismosch well, actually `javac` should work fine. But `java` will only work for non-GUI programs in the Windows 10 Ubuntu subsystem.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't knew that. I just tried the code in a programm called "Eclipse" and there the code worked as expected. My professor said to learn java editors like the vi-editor are way better than programms like Eclipse.

Comment: @Rismosch I'm a professional with 30 years of experience, and I use Eclipse... Anyway, vi is not exclusive to Linux. You can install [vim](http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc) on your Windows and use it if you like. It's not really a Java editor, though. Just a plaintext editor.

Comment: I do believe you. My professor just said it's not good for _learning_, because it automatically shows you mistakes and tells you how to fix them, without you understanding it. He sais that Eclipse helps you run the code, not helping you understnad it.